# Ingress configuration on Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to GKE Can please help to understand What does this statement mean .

> You cannot manually configure LoadBalancer features using the Google Cloud SDK or the Google Cloud console. You must use BackendConfig or FrontendConfig Kubernetes resources.

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if resolve your que and answer by accepting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple words, if you are running the **GKE** with **GCE** **ingress controller**, **serviceType** **LoadBalancer** yaml, you have to use the **BackendConfig** or **FrontendConfig** to configure the Load Balancer.

**BackendConfig** or **FrontendConfig** is used to configure the **Load Balancer**. Suppose you are looking for **HTTP > HTTPS** **redirect**, **SSL policy** it's not suggested to **set/configure** the from **GCP console** instead use the **YAML** config.

[Backend Doc ref](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#associating_backendconfig_with_your_ingress) & [Frontend Doc ref](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#configuring_ingress_features_through_frontendconfig_parameters)